# multiply pandas dataframe of different dimensions

Tags: python, pandas

I have this

```
df1:

A    6
B    4
C    2
```

and this

```
df2:
              A       B       C
Date
2014-09-29    4       7       9
2014-09-30    5       5       5
2014-10-01    7       6       8
2014-10-02    4       7       9
2014-10-03    5       5       5
2014-10-04    7       6       8
```

I would like to obtain a resulting dataframe that multiplies each corresponding value of df1 by its corresponding column in df2

Comment: What exactly is df1 as in what are the column, index values as what you've posted is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiple by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) or `*` with `Series` (column of `df1`):

```
print (df1)
   col
A    6
B    4
C    2


df = df2.mul(df1['col'])
print (df)
             A   B   C
Date                  
2014-09-29  24  28  18
2014-09-30  30  20  10
2014-10-01  42  24  16
2014-10-02  24  28  18
2014-10-03  30  20  10
2014-10-04  42  24  16
```

Or:

```
df = df2 * df1['col']
print (df)
             A   B   C
Date                  
2014-09-29  24  28  18
2014-09-30  30  20  10
2014-10-01  42  24  16
2014-10-02  24  28  18
2014-10-03  30  20  10
2014-10-04  42  24  16
```